# Sxa Search Result infinite loop after adding social media share component

Tags: sxa

i added "search result component" to a page in sitecore and it returned data , till i added the "social media share component" in the search result variant , then it got stuck and entered an infinite loop - showing the loading image only.

Comment: What have you checked, have you looked at the error logs or the console? What errors are you seeing there?

Comment: i tried another component the issue not only related to social , the issue related to adding any component in search result variant

Comment: Ok - but what about log files. There is no way to identify what the error might be from your current post.